# How could be vectorized this several loops in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

I was trying to find some way to run this script, but it takes a lot of time of processing, so i decided to try to "vectorize" them, unsuccessfully.

```
B = sparse(NxNy,NxNy)

Ny=246;
Nx=190;

for n1y = 1:Ny
 for n1x = 1:Nx;
  n1 = (n1y-1)*Nx+n1x;
  for n2y = 1:Ny
   for n2x = 1:Nx;

       n2 = (n2y-1)*Nx+n2x;
       dx12 = xax(n1x) - xax(n2x);  
       dy12 = xay(n1y) - xay(n2y);
       r12 = sqrt(dx12^2+dy12^2);
       B(n1,n2) = 0.8 * exp((-1/2)*(r12/300));

   end      
  end
 end
end
```

I tried to vectorize n1y, n1x, n2y and 2nx, but as Matlab deals with vectors, vectors with different sizes cannot be executed (calculate n1 and n2), so, I stopped.

size(xax) = 190

size(xay) = 246

Comment: Give sizes for xax, xay and B. Did you initialized B = zeros(b1, b2) before loop?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, xax  (1,190) and xay (1,246)
I initialized B with sparse() function:
B = sparse(NxNy,NxNy)

Comment: Also put semicolon after (n2y-1)*Nx+n2x - output to console slows down execution significantly.

Comment: Ok, I changed. I still had not placed it because I was testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reduce time of inner cycle from 0.027 seconds to 0.00046 seconds just by changing cycle to matrix operation

Additionally, there is 5% improvement, if distance computation is taken out of the loop.

And reducing second inner cycle change their time from 0.11 seconds to 0.0065 seconds.

```
close all; clear all;

Nx=190;
Ny=246;

xax = unidrnd(10, [1,Nx]);
xay = unidrnd(10, [1,Ny]);
B = sparse(Nx * Ny, Nx * Ny);

dx2 = repmat(xax, length(xax), 1);
dy2 = repmat(xay, length(xay), 1);

dx2 = (dx2 - dx2').^2 / 90000;
dy2 = (dy2 - dy2').^2 / 90000;

n1x = 1:Nx;
n2x = 1:Nx;
for n1y = 1:Ny
  Y1 = (n1y-1)*Nx;
  for n2y = 1:Ny
    tic
    Y2 = (n2y-1)*Nx;
    DY = dy2(n1y, n2y);
    n1 = Y1 + n1x;
    n2 = Y2 + n2x;
    r12 = sqrt(dx2 + DY);
    B(n1,n2) = 0.8 * exp((-1/2)*(r12));
    toc
  end
end
```

Comment: It is incredible! It saves a really good time, do you have any other ideas to to decrease the execution time?

Comment: By taking as much as possible outside of the loops.

Comment: I was able to take second loop out and now it's ~1107 times faster comparing to original algorithm.